# Проблема с циклом чтения файла

Tags: python, json, pandas, url

Я беру из файла `id` товаров и подставляю их в url запрос.
Все идет отлично, пока `id` в файле не становиться слишком много (около 60.000), тогда я пытаюсь циклом доставать с файла первые 400 `id`, потом следующие 400 и так до конца.

Но код почему-то не работает и отправляет сразу все 60.000 id в url запрос.
Помогите пожалуйста определить место ошибки.

Код:

```py
import json
import itertools
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_product_data():
    # Читаем айдишники из файла в один большой список
    with open('id.json', 'r') as file:
        ids = [line.strip() for line in file]

    # Делаем из одномерного списка двумерный список каждые n элементов
    count = 400
    ids = [ids[n:n + count] for n in range(0, len(ids), count)]

    # Отправляем GET и получаем результат
    result = []
    for group in ids:
        payload_data = {'product_ids': ' '.join(group)}
        f = requests.get('https://example.com/get?', params=payload_data)
        if f.status_code == 200:
            print('Good')

        if 'json' in f.headers['content-type']:
            print('Very Good')
        result.append(f.json())
        d = f.json()
    return d

#разбор словарь получаемых данных
def flatten_dict(d):
    def expand(key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return [ (key + '.' + k, v) for k, v in flatten_dict(value).items() ]
        else:
            return [ (key, value) ]

    items = [ item for k, v in d.items() for item in expand(k, v) ]

    return dict(items)

# формируем DataFrem
d = get_product_data()
data = d['data']
data = list(map(flatten_dict, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df[["id","title","price","old_price","href","comments_amount","sell_status","category_id","mpath","tag.name","tag.priority"]])
```

Comment: А как вы определяете, что идут сразу все?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример содержимого файла « id.json» (10 строк)?

Comment: @BioCommand в вашем файле всего одна строка? Ну тогда совершенно неудивительно, что всё читается целиком, ведь вы читаете файл по строкам, а строка в файле одна.

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться, в каком формате записано содержимое файла. Это JSON? Откуда он берётся?

Comment: Ну тогда просто `ids = json.load(file)` и весь остальной код должен нормально заработать

Comment: А, ну да, теперь же числа нужно преобразовать обратно в строку `' '.join(str(x) for x in group)`

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы предлагаю прибегнуть к постепенной отладке кода.

Пусть у нас есть файл со следующим содержимым:

```
181862304
73246875
46777912
1128570
79793930
19682005
175847008
154757366
61314671
56019630
```

Сначала нужно убедиться, что чтение файла по частям и формирование `payload` работает правильно. Для этого вместо того, чтобы отправлять запросы на сервер просто будем записывать значения `payload` в текстовый файл:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    ids = [line.strip() for line in file]

chunksize = 3

with open("c:/temp/debug.txt", "w") as file:
    for ii in range(0, len(ids), chunksize):
        chunk = ids[ii: ii + chunksize]
        payload_data = {'product_ids': ' '.join(chunk)}
        print(payload_data, file=file)
```

---

результат (`C:\temp\debug.txt`):

```
{'product_ids': '181862304 73246875 46777912'}
{'product_ids': '1128570 79793930 19682005'}
{'product_ids': '175847008 154757366 61314671'}
{'product_ids': '56019630'}
```

После этого добавьте код отладки для того, чтобы понять на каком значении `payload` получаете ошибку:

```
chunksize = 400 # укажите нужное значение

with open("c:/temp/debug.txt", "w") as file:
    for ii in range(0, len(ids), chunksize):
        chunk = ids[ii: ii + chunksize]
        payload_data = {'product_ids': ' '.join(chunk)}

        r = requests.get('https://example.com/get?', params=payload_data)
        if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok or 'json' not in r.headers['content-type']:
            print(f'The request with following payload has failed: {payload_data}')
        ...
```