# Ошибка при формировании DataFrame: KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

Tags: python, json, парсер, pandas, анализ-данных

Возникает ошибка при формировании DataFrame:

```
 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['title', 'parent_id'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

На такой url запрос:

```
https://shop.com/full?front-type=xl&lang=ru
```

Я получаю такой JSON в ответ:

```
data: {
2416: {},
3361: {
id: 3361,
title: "Смартфоны, ТВ и электроника",
parent_id: 0,
manual_url: "",
border: 0,
logos: [],
icon_src: null,
category_id: 4627949,
top_category_id: 4627949,
target_blank: 0,
banner_mobile_src: "",
on_subdomain: 0,
is_portal: false,
banner_href: "",
banner_src: "",
children: {},
popular_categories: [],
outer_link: false
},
4306: {},
```

Следующим этапом я разбираю этот JSON и из нужных мне значений формирую DataFrame.
Данный пример кода работал, пока я не стал отравлять `id` товаров в url запросы циклом.
После этого стала возникать представленная выше ошибка.

Весь код.:

```
import json
import itertools
import requests
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


url = ""

colums = ['id.title', 'idt','parent_id','manual_url']

r = requests.get(url)

d = pd.json_normalize(r.json().get(('data')))
df =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df.columns.tolist())
print(df[['title','parent_id']])
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: ok, теперь понятно какие у вас входные данные. Осталось только разобраться с тем, что вы хотите получить __на выходе__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```sql
url = "https://xl-catalog-api.rozetka.com.ua/v2/goods/getDetails?"
payload_data = {'product_ids':'[181862304,73246875,46777912,1128570,79793930,19682005,175847008,48664822,83165259,166123028,196115893,128726386,202437139]'}
cols = ['id', 'title', 'price', 'old_price', 'href', 'comments_amount','sell_status', 'category_id','mpath','tag.name','tag.priority']

r = requests.get(url, params=payload_data)

df = pd.json_normalize(r.json().get("data"))[cols]
```

---

Результат:

```
In [111]: df
Out[111]:
           id                          title  price  old_price                           href  comments_amount  sell_status  category_id  \
0    73246875  Планшет Lenovo Tab E10 2/1...   3999       4699  http://rozetka.com.ua/leno...               35    available       130309
1    46777912  Графический планшет Wacom ...   3899          0  https://rozetka.com.ua/wac...               38    available        83199
2     1128570  Адаптер подключения Grand-...    269        269  https://rozetka.com.ua/gra...             2212    available        80043
3    79793930  Сетевой фильтр Patron SP-1...    126          0  https://rozetka.com.ua/pat...               10    available        84863
4    19682005  Коннектор Patron FTP RJ 45...    132          0  https://rozetka.com.ua/pat...               20    available      4631537
5   175847008  Настольная подставка под м...    849        849  https://rozetka.com.ua/bec...                6    available      4630662
6    48664822  Беспроводной bluetooth кар...    333          0  https://rozetka.com.ua/486...                9    available       102876
7    83165259  Детский беспроводной микро...    450        890  https://rozetka.com.ua/831...                6    available       102876
8   166123028  Портативный беспроводной к...    560        870  https://rozetka.com.ua/166...                0    available       102876
9   196115893  Детское пианино синтезатор...    990       1090  https://rozetka.com.ua/196...                1    available       102876
10  128726386  Гибкое пианино для детей B...    849          0  https://rozetka.com.ua/128...                0  unavailable       102876

                            mpath    tag.name  tag.priority
0                  .80253.130309.      action           6.0
1                   .80253.83199.  popularity           4.0
2             .80253.80256.80043.  popularity           4.0
3             .80253.80256.84863.  popularity           4.0
4   .80253.4630100.1230965.463...  recomended           1.0
5           .80253.80256.4630662.         NaN           NaN
6   .88468.4265805.100784.102876.         NaN           NaN
7   .88468.4265805.100784.102876.         NaN           NaN
8   .88468.4265805.100784.102876.         NaN           NaN
9   .88468.4265805.100784.102876.         NaN           NaN
10  .88468.4265805.100784.102876.         NaN           NaN
```

Comment: @BioCommand, приведите пример данных из входного файла (как они есть в файле - не меняя их ) в [вашем первом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1128386/211923)

Comment: Для того чтобы вам давали рабочие и проверенные ответы надо приводить __воспроизводимые__ примеры данных ;)